# Call decorated class method upon __init__()

Tags: python, pandas, python-decorators

I am trying to return a dataframe (that is the result of a function concatenating two dataframes) upon class initialization. Since I cannot use the decorator directly upon the **init**, I have to call the decorator upon a separate method and pass this to init.

Unfortunately, the desired resulting dataframe is not returned when I instantiate the class?

I have tried wrapping the function using functools 'wraps' however I am still not getting the desired result, despite no errors being thrown

```py
from functools import wraps

# the decorator function 
def join_results(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def join_df_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    close_df.columns = map(str.lower, close_df.columns)
    close_df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(close_df.dates))
    model_preds_df.columns = map(str.lower, model_preds_df.columns) 
    model_preds_df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(model_preds_df.dates))
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

class BackTestModelPNL(object):
  """test decorator"""

  def __init__(self, close_df: pd.DataFrame, model_preds_df: pd.DataFrame):
    self.close_df = close_df
    self.model_preds_df = model_preds_df
    self._initial_df = self.return_init_df()

  @property
  def initial_df(self):
    return self._initial_df

  # call decorator
  @join_results
  def return_init_df(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self

# test that the class inits and returns joined results dataframe
df = BackTestModel(close_df, model_preds_df)
```

The Class is called without error but the desired result (the joined dataframe) is not returned when the class is instantiated

Comment: "I am trying to return a dataframe upon class initialisation" Can you clarify your use case? Classes are supposed to provide instances upon initialisation. If you want to return something else, why not use a regular function?

Comment: The intention is to join separate dataframes to perform a series a of checks up. The class is intended to perform these checks, but also to silently join the two disparate frames beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__()` should always return None.

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**init**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

> Because **new**() and **init**() work together in constructing objects
>   (**new**() to create it, and **init**() to customize it), no non-None
>   value may be returned by **init**(); doing so will cause a TypeError
>   to be raised at runtime.

You can do this using property which is a more pythonic way. The `return_init_df()` function can compute your initial data frame.

```
# Define class 
class BackTestModel(object):
  def __init__(self, close_df: pd.DataFrame, model_preds_df: pd.DataFrame):
    self.close_df = close_df
    self.model_preds_df = model_preds_df
    self._initial_df = self.return_init_df()

  @property
  def initial_df(self):
    return self._initial_df


# test that the class inits and returns joined results dataframe
df = BackTestModel(close_df, model_preds_df)
inital_df = df.initial_df
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! Could you please explain how the property decorator integrates with the @join_results decorator? Do you mean that the initial-df method would be where I define the join_results logic? Thanks!

Comment: The logic could be in 'return_init_df()' which could return or set the _inital_df. The property is like a getter to access the _inital_df

Comment: I have adjusted the original code to implement your solution, would please be so kind as to see if this is what you meant as an implementation? unfortunately I am still not getting a df upon init? Many thanks for your help, much appreciated